# nodejs streams promise doesn't reject on error

Tags: javascript, node.js, sftp

I have a code that fetches CSV files from an SFTP and parses them, The following function doesn't reject when there is an error (permission denied) when opening the file

```
const getCSV = (fileName) => {
    const results = []
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!fileName) {
            resolve(results)
        }
        sftp
            .createReadStream(`${directoryToFetch}/${fileName}`)
            .on('error', (e) => {
                console.error(`Failed parsing CSV ${e}, ${directoryToFetch}/${fileName}`)
                return reject(new Error(`Failed parsing CSV ${e}: ${directoryToFetch}/${fileName}`))
            })
            .pipe(csv({ skipLines: 1, separator: '\t' }))
            .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
            .on('end', () => {
                return resolve(results)
            })
            .on('error', () => {
                return reject('Failed parsing CSV')
            })
    })
}
```

the function does get to the .on('error') event and it executes the reject but in the for loop that awaits on the results from the function I don't get the .catch triggered by the rejection of the promise

```
    const filesList = await getRelevantFileList()
    const processedFiles = []
    for (const file of filesList) {
        try {
            const { name } = file
            let dataFromFile = await getCSV(name)
            const dataToInsert = dataFromFile.filter((entry) => entry.SharesOutstanding > 0)
            dataFromFile = []
            processedFiles.push(file)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`${error} Unable to fetch ${file}`)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the `end` event on the piped stream trigger first by any chance? Then the promise would already be `resolve()`d.

Comment: no, it doesn't trigger, only the error event triggers

Answer (score 0):

One issue I can see here is that

```js
if (!fileName) {
  resolve(results)
}
```

Is missing a return, so it should be

```js
if (!fileName) {
  return resolve(results)
}
```

This means that if the fileName is missing you will both an error and a resolve

Comment: The issue is that it doesn't reject the promise on the 'error' event

Comment: are you sure that "end" isn't called before "error"?

Comment: I am sure, we have decided to move away from the streams solution